# Trying to find the occurrences of a string in a linear algorithm

Tags: java

Ok i reformatted what im trying to do. The output has to return the values below.

I know I need to iteration using a multidimesion loop to check each character but im pretty stumped as far as how to go about it.

```
String str = "what has the time"


value1 = "hatw hat has the time"
value2 = "wwhhaatt hhaas the time"
value3 = "what has thetime"


output line 1: 00001
output line 2: 00256
output line 3: 00000
```

Comment: You need to provide a set of input data (at least 5 input records) and corresponding output.  It is not possible to figure out what you are trying to do from what you've shown.

Comment: @user9075156 can you provide more info, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable using [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), its methods and working could save you A LOT of hassle.

```
String str = "purrpppppllleeee ssaiyan purple saiyan";
String findStr = "purple saiyan";
String regexStr = "";
for(int i = 0; i < findStr.length(); i++)
{
    regexStr += findStr.charAt(i)+"+";
}
regexStr += "\\s*";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regexStr);
Matcher m = patt.matcher(str);
int count = 0;
while(m.find())
{
    count++;
}
```

The loops are just adding a plus after every character of the `findStr`.

Adding a plus after a character tells the matcher that there may be multiple occurrences of the letter.

At the end, the matcher finds how many times the phrase `findStr` has occurred (in the form of the code)

Comment: Explaining in a moment

Comment: You need to expand this answer, and give the basic idea of what is in the link you provided.

Comment: I am. Went out for a bit is all :/

Comment: Thanks! I would wait to post until you have a full answer next time, though.

Comment: My bad... Had to go out urgently, and almost forgot about this answer